# How to enable saving of replay recordings in Campaign

Tags: starcraft-2, recording

How do I enable recording of replays of Campaign missions in Starcraft 2 (Legacy of the Void). Is that possible? I'm talking about the Observer/replay feature in Starcraft where in records how player played the game.

I found the 'Replay' tab in outer-most menu next to Campaign, Multiplayer but it only contains my replays for multiplayer. Also this folder is empty

```
Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\<no>\<no>\Replays\Campaign
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to have replays of campaign missions, so recording isn't possible. This feature is only available for 1v1s 2v2s 3v3s 4v4s and archon mode.